# Consistency of complete-case analysis or mixed random variable mean estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence, means

Let $Y$ be a random variable and $R \in \{0,1\}$ a random variable that indicates whether $Y$ is observed or missing

\begin{equation}
Y \cdot R = \begin{cases}
Y & R=1, \\
0 & R=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Let $(Y_{i},R_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ denote a sample of size n.

In complete case analysis (CC) or listwise deletion, we delete all missing values and just work with all observed variables.

In the following [course "Statistical Methods for Analysis With Missing Data"](https://rmisstastic.netlify.app/tutorials/Davidian_course_StatisticalMethodsMissingData_2017/Davidian_course_chapter1_2017.pdf), the listwise deletion or complete-case mean estimator is estimated by

\begin{equation}
\widehat{\mu}^c=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N R_i Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N R_i}
\end{equation}

It is shown that in case $R_{i}$ is independent of $Y_{i}$, when $Y$ *is missing completely at random* (**MCAR**), that estimator $\widehat{\mu}^c$ is consistent.

Quote of the proof [from page 22]:

"It follows that, as $N \rightarrow \infty$, by the weak law of large numbers,
\begin{equation}
\widehat{\mu}^c=\frac{N^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^N R_i Y_i}{N^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^N R_i} \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} \frac{E(R Y)}{E(R)}=\frac{E(R) E(Y)}{E(R)}=\mu. \ \text{"}
\end{equation}

It is evident that
\begin{equation}
           Z_{n} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} R_{i} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} E \left( R \right) \neq 0,
\end{equation}
where $E(R) \neq 0$. However if we want to apply the continuous mapping theorem to get $\frac{1}{Z_{n}} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{E(R)}$, the following needs to be satisfied

$$Z_{n} \neq 0, \ \forall n, \ \text{a.s.} $$

**Questions**

1. Why should consistency hold ?

Precisely: Why is $$Z_{n} \neq 0, \ \forall n, \ \text{a.s . ?} $$

2. If $R_{i} \sim Bernoulli (p)$ and consistency is satisfied, how do I compute the bias

\begin{equation}
E \left(
\mu^{c}
\right) - \mu.
\end{equation}

Comment: We do not need $Z_n\neq 0$ for all $n$ almost surely. We just need, almost surely, existence of (possibly random) index $M$ such that $Z_n\neq 0$ for all $n\geq M$. In other words, almost surely we have that $Z_n\neq 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  So (1) It is not true that $Z_n\neq 0$ almost surely for all $n$. Clearly $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ may have significant probability of being zero. (2) The law of large numbers does not involve $E[1/\sum_{i=1}^nR_i]$, so that expectation is irrelevant to the previous discussion. In fact that expression is undefined due to the possibility of $1/0$.

Comment: This is also a case where the strong law of large numbers makes the argument easier (and stronger) than the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: The law of large numbers does not involve $E( \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} R_{i}}$, but my question was related to computation of bias $E(\mu^{c})-\mu$. Here we have $$E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{R_{i} Y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} R_{i}}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} E(E(\frac{R_{i} Y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} R_{i}}))$$...

Comment: The expression $E[1/\sum_{i=1}^nR_i]$ is undefined due to the undefined case $1/0$ occurring with positive probability.

Comment: Yes this is why I'm asking how one would compute the bias of such estimator. I will reformulate the question above to make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\{R_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(p)$ with $p\in (0,1]$. Suppose $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with mean $E[Y]$. Moreover suppose $\{R_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are independent.  Define:
$$\hat{\mu}_n= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n R_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nR_i} & \mbox{ if $\sum_{i=1}^n R_i\neq 0$} \\
0 & \mbox{ else} 
\end{array}\right.$$
Define $W_n=\sum_{i=1}^nR_i$.

Then
\begin{align}
E[\hat{\mu}_n] &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} E[\hat{\mu}_n|W_n=k]P[W_n=k]\\
&=0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} E[\hat{\mu}_n|W_n=k]P[W_n=k]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nE[R_iY_i|W_n=k]}{k}\right)P[W_n=k]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{E[Y]}{k}\sum_{i=1}^nE[R_i|W_n=k]\right)P[W_n=k]\\
&=E[Y]\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n R_i|W_n=k\right]P[W_n=k]\\
&=E[Y]\sum_{k=1}^{n} P[W_n=k]\\
&=E[Y]P[W_n\neq 0]\\
&=E[Y](1-(1-p)^n)
\end{align}
where we have used:

- $E[R_iY_i|W_n=k]=E[Y]E[R_i|W_n=k]\quad \forall i \in \{1, ... ,n\}$
- $E[\sum_{i=1}^n R_i|W_n=k]=k$

---

Thus
$$\boxed{E[\hat{\mu}_n]=E[Y] - (1-p)^nE[Y] \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}}$$
and this is asymptotically unbiased:
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[\hat{\mu}_n]=E[Y]$$

---

The above addresses the bias issue which was of main concern as revealed in the comments. Regarding the original question, I think a lot is resolved just by defining $\hat{\mu}_n=0$ in the previously undefined case  $\sum_{i=1}^nR_i=0$ (which, for each $n$, is a case of positive probability). For what it is worth, the strong law of large numbers (SLLN) seems easier to use here: Define events $A, B, C$ as follows:
\begin{align}
A &= \left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nR_i = p\right\}\\
B &= \left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nR_iY_i = pE[Y] \right\}\\
C &= \left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\hat{\mu}_n=E[Y]\right\}
\end{align}
We know by the SLLN that $P[A]=1$ and $P[B]=1$. We also see that if $A$ and $B$ are both true then $C$ must be true, so
$$A\cap B \subseteq C$$
which implies
$$P[A\cap B] \leq P[C]$$
On the other hand, since $P[A]=1$ and $P[B]=1$ then we know $P[A\cap B]=1$. Thus $1\leq P[C]$, so $P[C]=1$. Thus, $\hat{\mu}_n\rightarrow E[Y]$ almost surely.

Comment: The law of large numbers deals with i.i.d. random variables. It does not say $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}\hat{\mu}_n = E[\hat{\mu}_n]$ because (i) $\{\hat{\mu}_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are not i.i.d. random variables; (ii) $E[\hat{\mu}_n]$ depends on $n$ (see above answer) and so it does not make sense for a limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ to give an answer that depends on $n$.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to define $A = \{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n R_i(\omega) = p\}$, and define $B$ and $C$ similarly to emphasize these are sets of outcomes $\omega$ that lead to the desired limit. Since $\{R_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d., the SLLN states that $P[A]=1$. Similarly the SLLN states that $P[B]=1$. The SLLN says nothing about $P[C]$, but we can see that if $\omega$ is a particular outcome  that is in both $A$ and $B$, then we must have $\omega \in C$.

Comment: yes sorry for the mistake. Yet, how did you get to $C=\left\{\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n R_i Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n R_i} =E[Y]\right\}$ ?

Comment: I defined $C$ as that event (with the goal of hoping to prove $P[C]=1$). Then I observed that if $\omega \in A\cap B$, then $\omega \in C$. This holds by the calculus fact that the ratio of limits is the limit of the ratio (assuming the numerator and denominator have well defined limits, and the limit in the denominator is nonzero). Note that if $\omega$ is a particular outcome then $\{R_i(\omega)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is just a sequence of (nonrandom) real numbers and all the calculus limit properties apply.

Comment: Great, thank you :)